# How to add a 'section trail' as a side bar for navagation? Use JS/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a really large page that have many elements . Sometime I wish I can jump back and forth between different elements.

I have seen that some pages have a page trail, which basically is a list of browse history:

```
|page1>>|page2>>|page3>>|page4>>
```

with the last one is current page. If we click `page5`, we open page5, with the trail:

```
|page2>>|page3>>|page4>>|page5>>
```

now if we chick back `page4`, we open page4, with the trail shows:

```
|page2>>|page3>>|page5>>|page4>>
```

I am think to get a similar one that works with the elements within one page. It will be a div with sticky position on the left side, so no matter which section I am, I can quickly jump to the last(or last last last) section by just one click.

Can this be achieved? (by javascript)

Thank you in advance!

I did some search according the suggestions. and propose the following, please see if there is some point that I am misisng.

1. I create a array of the positions of all the anchors, and a trail array to contain trails
2. check the scroll point, if falls in to certain scroll point, then, 
    1) if slot available, append the trail
    2) if trail array is full, rotate
    3) if trail exist, switch

Comment: They are most commonly called "bread crumb trails" and you should be able to find it all over GOOGLE!

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. That will be a good starting point for me.

Comment: As to your last question. Yes, they can be generated with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a whole page full of JS and jQuery solutions!

[Breadcrumb Trail Scripts](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript%20breadcrumb%20trail)

Comment: Hi, I looked this but I am still confused about how to get this work with elements inside on page.